# Древовидность в списке

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Алоха, господа кодеры. Я вообще ни разу не программист, но упорно пытаюсь понять, почему вот этот код:

```
if (!isset($location_result->post_parent )) {
  $locations_select .= '<option value="' . esc_attr($location_result->ID) . '" ' . ($location_result->ID == $l ? 'selected' : '') . '>' . $location_result->post_title . '</option>';
} else {
  $locations_select .= '<option value="' . esc_attr($location_result->ID) . '" ' . ($location_result->ID == $l ? 'selected' : '') . '>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' . $location_result->post_title . '</option>';
}
```

Заставляет сдвигаться вообще все элементы списка, даже те, у которых отсутствует родительская страница. Вопрос по вордпресс, соответственно.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что поле post_parent у объекта post присутствует всегда. А значит, isset всегда возвращает true. Первая строка должна выглядеть так:

```
if ($location_result->post_parent == 0) {
```

потому что у тех страниц/записей, что не имеют родителей, post_parent равен 0.